# Meaning of "compromise of information"

Tags: meaning

What does "compromise of information" mean. Here it is in context: "The leak has resulted in the the compromise of information."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the integrity of that information has been weakened/damaged. That information has been leaked/shared and is now no longer secret or it has been accessed or is able to be accessed by someone (or someones) who isn't supposed to have access to it. So now you have to seriously question whether it is safe for you to use that information or not.

See it this way - imagine putting your credit card details in a safe and then that safe is broken into and your credit card details are now posted on a public forum/website. The `leak` has now resulted in the `compromise of your credit card information.`

Comment: When a leak compromises information, the privacy of that data is in question. Normally, we'd take action as though the data is stolen, to play it safe, but compromised does not equal stolen. While a broken safe means theft, compromised means *maybe breached*.

Comment: I'm just not certain that "the information" is compromised. Wouldn't a person need to say "the security of the information has been compromised" ? The sercurity is what is compromised.. the information is still all there (could be the "privacy" comprised too?)  I ok if someone corrects me on this though.